# How to optimize time for writing a lot files (saving frames from video)

Tags: c++, file-io, kinect

### Background

I am currently working on a small application that grabs the RGB and depth map streams from a Microsoft Kinect device and saves them on disk for future analysis. Whn I run the program it shall output each frame as a separate image on disk.

The framerate of the Kinect is 30fps, but there are two sources so make this (approximately) 60fps. If I naively try to just save each frame when it arrives I will get dropped frames as is demonstrated by the bundled [freenect/record.c](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/fakenect/record.c) application.

I rewrote the application to use one thread that grabs the frames from the device and pushes them to the back of a double ended list (`std::deque`). Then there are two threads that each pop frames from the front of the double ended list and saves the frames to disk.
When the recording is turned off, there is a potentially large number of frames left in the list that still need to be recorded, so before exiting we let the two save threads do their work until finished.

### Now the actual problem

Although the problem of dropped frames is solved, writes to the filesystem are still quite slow. Is there any good way to speed up the file creation on disk?
Currently, the function `dump_frame` looks like this:

```
static void
dump_frame(struct frame* frame)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char filename[512]; /* plenty of space! */

    sprintf(filename, "d-%f-%u.pgm", get_time, frame->timestamp);

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "P5 %d %d 65535\n", frame->width, frame->height);
    fwrite(frame->data, frame->size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I am running Fedora 14 x64, so the solution only have to concern Linux as operating system.

Comment: How large is each frame (in bytes). Is it really the file creation that is slow or the writing of data? I create several thousand of tiny files on OSX without problem, but when the files grow larger it takes a lot more time.

Comment: Would it be possible to write them all to the same file and then later split that file?

Comment: Frame buffers are set to 640x480x3 bytes. Yes, writing to one file and later splitting it is an option but unless it gives me a really great speed up it is not really worth it.

Comment: how about dumping in a single file, then splitting it into smaller one when time is not that critical? Also you may want to use a file system better suited for handling large amounts of smaller files (ReiserFS, maybe?)

Comment: I get much more consistent speed if I write to the same file (left housekeeping for the file system). What drive(s) do you have. You are trying to get a sustained rate of 60MB/s. If you have a lot of ram, create a ram disk and save there first.

Comment: Unfortunately, mucking about with the filesystem is not suitable as default option as I am not administrating the computer(s) the program runs on. It is however a valid point, and will probably do something like that when running on any machine where it is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Also, @Roger, if you put your answers in an actual answer, I'd be happy to up vote it as they are still valid, although not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to measure what takes time in your specific case. Is it creating multiple files or actually writing the image data to disk?

When I tested on my local system with OSX and an Intel SSD X25M 2G I noticed a huge variation in writes when writing multiple 1MB files vs writing 1 multi MB file. This is probably due to housekeeping of the filesystem and will vary depending on the file system you have.

To avoid the housekeeping you could site all your images to the same file and split it later. However, the data you are saving needs about 60MB sustained speed which is quite high.

An alternative if you have a lot of memory is to create a ram disk and store the images there first and later move them on to the persistent file system. With a 6GB ram disk you could store about 100 seconds of video.

Comment: I am accepting this, as a slow file system was the big culprit in my case.

Answer (score 1):

A possible improvement would to explicitly set the buffering of `fp` to full using [setvbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setvbuf/):

```
const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 16;
fp = fopen(filename, "w");
setvbuf(fp, 0, _IOFBF, BUFFER_SIZE)); /* Must be immediately after the open. */
fprintf(fp, "P5 %d %d 65535\n", frame->width, frame->height);
fwrite(frame->data, frame->size, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

You could profile using different buffer sizes to determine which provides the best performance.

Comment: That did not help speed up things at all, unfortunately.

Comment: I mistakenly set size of buffer to zero in my original post, updated specifying a buffer size. Not sure if you noticed that or not.

Comment: Also check if `setvbuf()` returns 0 to ensure it was successfully configured.

Comment: I tried setting the buffer to both data that was equal to (or slightly larger) than the data to write, and to half the size.